# Traverse a List Using an Iterator?

Tags: c++, stl

I need sample for traversing a list using C++.

Comment: Easy solution on Google'ing : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/List/TraverseaListUsinganIterator.htm

Comment: "now you're just being plain lazy" For all we know the poster may be an expert in some other programming language. If you don't want to help him, just don't. I was Googling 3 years later and found the answer very useful.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The sample for your problem is as follows

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <list>
  using namespace std;

  typedef list<int> IntegerList;
  int main()
  {
      IntegerList    intList;
      for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
         intList.push_back(i * 2);
      for (IntegerList::const_iterator ci = intList.begin(); ci != intList.end(); ++ci)
         cout << *ci << " ";
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Easy solution : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/List/TraverseaListUsinganIterator.htm

Answer (score 20):

To reflect new additions in C++ and extend somewhat outdated solution by @karthik, [starting from C++11 it can be done shorter](http://ideone.com/pfeq7y) with [auto](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) specifier:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

typedef list<int> IntegerList;

int main()
{
  IntegerList intList;
  for (int i=1; i<=10; ++i)
   intList.push_back(i * 2);
  for (auto ci = intList.begin(); ci != intList.end(); ++ci)
   cout << *ci << " ";
}
```

or [even easier](http://ideone.com/KdbjmH) using [range-based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

typedef list<int> IntegerList;

int main()
{
    IntegerList intList;
    for (int i=1; i<=10; ++i)
        intList.push_back(i * 2);
    for (int i : intList)
        cout << i << " ";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you mean an STL `std::list`, then here is a simple example from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/begin/.

```
// list::begin
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main ()
{
  int myints[] = {75,23,65,42,13};
  std::list<int> mylist (myints,myints+5);

  std::cout << "mylist contains:";
  for (std::list<int>::iterator it=mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;

  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although you should use `const_iterator` rather than `iterator` if you don't need to modify the list.

Comment: does the iterator remove elements from the list and reduce its size?

Answer (score 0):

now you can just use [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<int> intList;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
        intList.push_back(i * 2);
    for (auto i:intList)
        cout << i << " ";
    return 0;
}
```