# Can we put vector<string> to the list in C++ ？

Tags: c++

Like this:

list< vector < string > > ?

if the answer is yes,how I use it to print each elements of the list by For Cycle ?

Thanks everyone.I know how to print list< int >,which can be traversed by FOR CYCLE.But in fact, if I use FOR CYCLE and iterator to list< vector < string > >,I will be fail.

Comment: yes you can. Lists of containers is certainly possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Printing out the contents of a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750057/c-printing-out-the-contents-of-a-vector)

Comment: or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470331/traverse-a-list-using-an-iterator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your compiler is up to date with the standard:

```
std::list<std::vector<std::string>> lst;
for ( auto& vec : lst ) // Iterate through all std::vector's
   for ( auto& str : vec ) // Iterate through all std::string's
       std::cout << str << std::endl; // str is your std::string
```

Answer (score 0):

of course it is possible.
You can use an iterator to print each element of the list, try something like that:

```
list<vector<string> >::iterator it;
for(it=your_list.begin();it!=your_list.end();it++)
{
    //your code to print waht you want
    //it is a pointer to a vector<string>
    //...
}
```

Comment: why? you just have to put some code to print each element of each vectorI think

Comment: I am no sure. Maybe the system no overload the list<vector> ? You can try it.