# C++ - Overloading [] operator for a list of object pointers

Tags: c++, list, pointers, visual-c++

I have this  as a member of the class TASK.

```
list<Stimulation*> listOfStimulations;
```

And the rest of my class definition;

```
class Task
{
public:
    Task();
    Task(const Task& obj);
    Task(const Task&& obj);
    Task(string, list<Stimulation*>);
    Task& operator+=( Stimulation* obj);
    Stimulation* Task::operator[](int i) const;
};
#endif
```

And I want to be ale to access each Stimulation in the list.

I know I should be using vector, but using list is a requirement.

How would I overload []?

I've tried

```
    Stimulation* Task::operator[](int i) const
{
    list<Stimulation*>::const_iterator iter;
    iter = listOfStimulations.begin();
    advance(iter, i);
    return *iter;
}
```

My main issue is that this code isn't letting me access the elements of my list.

For example, listOfStimulations[i] does not work, and won't let me access the function display within the Stimulations class.

Comment: just use `begin()` and `end()`?

Comment: You could traversing the list with iterator until reached the nth node.

Comment: If it's the standard `list`, you can't; `operator[]` must be a non-static member function. The requirement of `std::list` suggests that this exercise wants to teach you how to program without relying on indexing.

Comment: @molbdnilo Sorry the exercise does specify to overload the [] operator.

Comment: @felix  I've tried 

https://paste.ee/p/j64wi

I'm not entirely sure if it does what I want. I want to be able to do listofStimulation[i]->display() to call the display function of the object.

Comment: @GillBates Excuse me if I'm wrong but doesn't that only use the first and last element?

Comment: You have to use them in an iterator check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470331/traverse-a-list-using-an-iterator

Comment: @user3701231 You're not supposed to overload the operator for `std::list`, but for your own `Task`. Which it appears you have already done, so it's not clear what the question is..

Comment: Okay the [] operator is to access Stimulation objects. Stimulation objects within the list. I am unable to do that.

Comment: When you update a post like now with the advance leave the original code there. write update and post it under it. so people can follow the progression of the thread.

Comment: Okay, very sorry. New to Stack Overflow. Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: @user3701231 I suspect there's a misunderstanding somewhere. You're supposed to use it like this: `Task t; t += some_stimulation; t[0]->display();`. You're not supposed to index the list inside `Task`.

Comment: @molbdnilo The thing is I'm supposed to access Stimulation objects using [] not Task. The list stores Stimulation objects  and is a member of the Task class. Sorry for being confusing

Comment: @molbdnilo Okay, I actually decided to fully grasp what you guys were saying. I completely understand now, thank you.

Comment: Off topic: It sounds like you are bound by assignment requirements but in the real world if you do a lot of iterating (as suggested by the `operator[]` requirement) as opposed to a lot of insert and remove, `std::list` may not be the tool you want to use. A more complete discussion: http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#list

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah I guess it was more on the terms of learning about iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to sequentially access a `list` is to use its [Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470331/traverse-a-list-using-an-iterator)

I suggest using the data structure that fits the requirements, and not trying to use a list just because.

This is how an Iterator works;

```
for (std::list<T>::iterator it = mylist.begin(); it != mylist.end(); ++it)
{
   if (...)
   {
      return *it;
   }
}
```

Now you can use `advance` to get "*random*" access;

```
std::list<T>::iterator it = mylist.begin();
std::advance(it,5);
return *it
```

Comment: Indeed, please see https://paste.ee/p/j64wi  the question is would this overload the [] for my list? or just my actual object.

Comment: Okay I've updated my code (see main post). I'm still having trouble access the display function for each stimulation.

Comment: try using the std::advance(it,5); the result of the std::advance(it,5); is the same as the result for mylist[5]

Comment: You're right it is, but it still doesn't let me access the members of the object inside the list. (Example, each object inside the list has the function display). I need to call that

Comment: what is the error you need to provide more information not just Not working... what is Display doing... how are you calling it.. and so on

Comment: It says no members available. display just outputs the private members inside the object.

Comment: stating the obvious but Is Display Public ? I suggest you closing this thread as it is no longer relevant to the first question asked and create another thread with the new question. That is why you are unable to access the members when using the above code.

Comment: yep indeed it is.

Comment: well I've actually been using an iterator before this thread, the reason why I posted  was because it wasn't working

Comment: unconditional `return` in a `for` loop?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified if you need a random access to each element in the list, given its index/position.

Anyway, as commented by molbdnilo, std::list has no operator[],
for description of the reasons, please read [this other question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112724/why-isnt-there-an-operator-for-a-stdlist).

The best you can do to access items in the list is using iterators, starting from [std::list::begin()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/begin/).

**edited**
Ok, based on your own comment, you need random access at each index-th item.
The code you linked in that comment looks like a good way to go.

Comment: Hi, essentially I wish to take my list and access each element within the square brackets. I know the reasons as to why, and I should be using a vector. It is a requirement unfortunately. I've tried this, https://paste.ee/p/j64wi and it doesn't do what I want it to do. listofStimulations[i]->display()

Comment: The only problem is I can't seem to use the list to access each pointer of object within, which leads me to believe I've done somethign wrong with my declaration.

Comment: Without a complete yet basic source code, it's hard to try to understand what you are really doing and what is needed to help you.
I suggest you to edit your question and add minimal source code to it (inline, not a linked page outside StackOverflow).

In the code you linked you are overloading operator[] of a class called Task (not , which is not defined anywhere in your code fragment.